# How to dump a Cassandra DB into a triplestore?

Tags: graph, cassandra, sparql, titan, triplestore

I have a Cassandra DB with a table containing values loaded from sensors, composed of 5 columns(user , sensor, observed param, value, timestamp). 
I would like to represent them in a triplestore in order to perform SPARQL query to get knowledge.

Initially i thought to Titan because it's based on Cassandra, but i don't find a way to automatically dump the Cassandra's table in a Titan graph.

Is there a way to do it with Titan or others triplestore?

Comment: Titan is a property graph database that uses Gremlin queries, not a [triplestore](https://www.w3.org/wiki/LargeTripleStores) that uses SPARQL queries.

Comment: Then you have to convert the database to RDF format first. I don't know if there are existing exporters, otherwise, if CSV export is possible, you could use a CSV2RDF tool and finally load the RDF data into a tripe store.

Comment: [Too many possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask); not a [good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [Virtuoso Commercial](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) could connect to Cassandra via ODBC, and [expose an RDF a/k/a Linked Data View of the remote table](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfviewsrdbms/). Or you could export the data from Cassandra to CSV or similar, and [load it into a Virtuoso (Open Source or Commercial) SQL table](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtCsvFileBulkLoader), and expose an RDF View of that. So many other options!